# Extract breadcrumb from html with regex and remove html tags

Tags: php, html, regex

How can I use regex to extract the words out of this html website breadcrumb. The breadcrumb is part of a html page I would load, so first I would need to extract the breadcrumb ul from the rest of the html and then I would want to strip all the html tags out so I am left with just the category words.

So first I would need to find this html section:

```
<ul itemprop="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
 <li><a href="/">Home</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li><a href="/inspiration/0.iroot">Inspiration</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li><a href="/inspiration/loft/CC_npccat_100031.icat">Loft</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li>First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life</li>
</ul>
```

Then the output I want is just the category's as text with the html tags removed, for example on this page this would be:

Home

Inspiration

Loft

First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life

Comment: what have you tried so far also is `regex` a requirement or are you open to other solutions?

Comment: For the last part, you just need `strip_tags`

Comment: Do you want to achieve this using php?
Maybe with a DOM parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `DomDocument` and `xpath` you can load the entire html and query for the `li` elements.
Then it's a matter of simply outputting the `nodeValue`

The `xpath->query` method below will search for all `li` elements that belong to a parent `ul` that has a class of `breadcrumb`

Example

```
$html = '
    <html>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <ul itemprop="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
                     <li><a href="/">Home</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
                     <li><a href="/inspiration/0.iroot">Inspiration</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
                     <li><a href="/inspiration/loft/CC_npccat_100031.icat">Loft</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
                     <li>First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$categories = $xpath->query('//ul[contains(@class,"breadcrumb")]/li');

foreach($categories as $category){
    print $category->nodeValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This will output

```
Home
Inspiration
Loft
First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life
```

Answer (score 0):

In short: [**don't**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Here's an example with a parser and xpath instead:

```
<?php
$html = '<ul itemprop="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
 <li><a href="/">Home</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li><a href="/inspiration/0.iroot">Inspiration</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li><a href="/inspiration/loft/CC_npccat_100031.icat">Loft</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li>First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life</li>
</ul>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
$categories = $xml->xpath('//li/a/text()');
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    echo $category[0] . "\n";
    // output Home, Inspiration, Loft
}
$items = $xml->xpath('//li[last()]');
echo $items[0][0]; // First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to parse DOM using Jquery:

```
<ul itemprop="breadcrumb" class="breadcrumb">
 <li><a href="/" class="bc" value="Home">Home</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li><a href="/inspiration/0.iroot" class="bc" value="Inspiration">Inspiration</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li><a href="/inspiration/loft/CC_npccat_100031.icat" class="bc" value="Loft">Loft</a><i class="ico-breadcrumb"></i></li>
 <li class="bc" value="First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life">First impressions count - bringing your hallway to life</li>
</ul>

<script>
    $(".bc").each(function(index, value) { 
        document.write($(this).attr('value')+' / '); 
    });
</script>
```

Comment: of course not @Jan, you are totally right but if he simply wants the output then both methods can be applied...